# Angular2 choose template dynamically according to service response

Tags: angular, components

I have a component called "Node" which should display a single post, but I have more than a post type and each type has its own view (layout).

So this component has an ID parameter which will be used to get a post response from a service then according to post type it should display the correct layout.

ex: `localhost/test_app/node/123` where 123 is the id parameter.

## Approach 1: using ngIf in the tamplate

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'node',
  directives: [Post, Project],
  template: `
    <post *ngIf="response.post.post_type == 'post'" content="response.post"></post>
    <project *ngIf="response.post.post_type == 'project'" content="response.post"></project>
  `,
})

export class Node{

  id: number;
  response: any;
  constructor(private _param: RouteParams,
              public service: Service
  ){
    this.id = +_param.get('id');
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.get(this.id).subscribe(
      res=> this.response = res.json()
    );
  }

}
```

## Approach 2: using dynamic component loader.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'node',
  directives: [Post, Project],
  template: '<div #container></div>'
})

export class Node{

  id: number;
  response: any;

  constructor(private _param: RouteParams,
              public service: Service,
              private loader:DynamicComponentLoader,
              private elementRef:ElementRef
  ){
    this.id = +_param.get('id');
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.get(this.id).subscribe(
      res=> {
          this.response = res.json();
          this.renderTemplate();
      }
    );
  }

  renderTemplate(template) {
    this.loader.loadIntoLocation(
      this.getCorrectTemplate(),
      this.elementRef,
      'container'
    )
  }

  getCorrectTemplate(){
    if(this.response.post.post_type == "post"){
        return '<post content="response.post"></post>';
    }
    else{
        return '<project content="response.post"></project>';
    }
  }

}
```

I'm wondering which approach is more efficient or if there is a better approach, please share it.

Comment: I prefer the JavaScript conditional like while we working in some project we faced lot of issues regarding performance as we were lot of conditional filtering on template and we move all that to JavaScript it show massive performance improvement.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava In Angularjs or Angular2?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer In Angularjs

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava you can't apply such experience from Angularjs to Angular2. They are entirely different frameworks and performance improvements are huge in Angular2 compared to Angular.js.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yup that true but may the approach is same for ng-if as functionality is same in both are same

Comment: It's not well supported to switch the template in JS anyway in Angular2. In Angular2 you usually just modify the model and let Angular control the DOM, otherwise you're working against the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a limited set of possible templates then `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitch` is a good approach. It allows you to use `[]` and `()` bindings between parent and child.

If you have a set of templates that are statically unknown and for example provided by a parameter then `*ngIf` doesn't work. Then `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` (replaces `DynamicComponentLoader`) is the right approach. For an example see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: in the answer's link, I'm getting error in webstorm on `this.type`, in updateComponent:  `this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.type).then...`

Comment: What's the exact error message? Types usually aren't necessary to run TS but static analysis might require them, depending on the configuration. I'm not familiar with this kind of configuration because I use TS only in Plunker and use Dart to develop with Angular2.

Comment: `unresolved variable type` it's expecting to define `type` in the component

Comment: It should refer the variable `@Input() type` (at the top of the class). If it is there, the error doesn't make sense to me. How much did you change the code? Can you try to reproduce in the Plunker?

Comment: ohh my bad, I'm using the id instead of the input so I removed it. lol

Comment: Ok, glad to hear you found the cause :)